# Is there a way to measure how long it takes for 'LOAD DATA INFILE' to complete

Tags: mysql, csv, time

Is there something similar to `time` command, used to measure process duration in terminal, for `mysql>` prompt, as I would like to see how much does it takes to finish `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` command on some large CSV file. Or maybe some other way of doing it?

Comment: `$ time mysqlimport db_name file_name` - would that work?

Comment: no, as that is not the same.. LOAD DATA INFILE is a much faster method of bulk importing large datasets

Comment: `The mysqlimport client provides a command-line interface to the LOAD DATA INFILE SQL statement`. So either the documentation is lying or you might not be correct?

Comment: sorry, didn't know it was a wrapper around LOAD DATA

Comment: Did it work correctly for you?

Comment: Great, that's all that matters. Good luck :)